# what is the payload size limit over websockets? ( push from nodejs server at 60 times a second )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, socket.io

I am sending a huge json data (several KBs) which consists of number of long arrays and sub arrays and long strings and integers as its properties from node js to UI/client at a rate of 60 times a second, i am getting 2 issues, one is the error below when i try to increase the payload size ( at smaller payload i am not seeing this error at all):

```
05:08:53.383 polling-xhr.js:232 GET http://localhost:XXXX/socket.io/?
X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=YYYYY&transport=polling&t=XXXXX 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Request.create @ polling-xhr.js:232
Request @ polling-xhr.js:155
XHR.request @ polling-xhr.js:86
XHR.doPoll @ polling-xhr.js:116
Polling.poll @ polling.js:118
Polling.doOpen @ polling.js:62
Transport.open @ transport.js:82
Socket.open @ socket.js:220
Socket @ socket.js:102
Socket @ socket.js:37
Manager.open.Manager.connect @ manager.js:205
(anonymous) @ manager.js:470
```

The second problem is that whatever i am trying to do at UI ( render something based on the received data) is spilling over the 16ms time window at which the next notification arrives from the server. So i see the FPS dropping to a low level ~15 depending on how long my JS takes to process the incoming data and render it on UI.

So the questions are: 
a) why the socket is erroring on large payload?
b) why the UI is showing a lower FPS instead of just dropping the frames it cannot handle (thereby maintaining 60 FPS)?
c) could i instead use HTTP to avoid throttling the UI from server thereby ensuring every cycle is fully finished before requesting the next one? but in this case is it possible to maintain 60 FPS?

Comment: webSockets don't just drop frames for you so unless your own UI code is realizing that you're behind and you're skipping the processing of some frames, then of course your code is going to process all the frames it was sent.  You don't need to use HTTP to stop getting overlapping frames.  You could just send a webSocket message when you're ready for the next frame and have the server not send another frame until it gets the "ready" message.  This is a primitive form of flow-control.

Comment: Possible to maintain 60fps?  It depends entirely upon your code and what it's doing and what type of system you're running it on.  You've included no code and given us no info about the level of processing or the typical type of target computer you're designing for so there's absolutely nothing we can say about whether you can maintain 60fps.  You can keep from falling behind with proper design, but whether that lets you render 60fps or not depends upon a lot of things you haven't shared and a bunch of testing.

Comment: The error message you show looks like a socket.io connection request that was refused because your server was too backed up to be able to handle another incoming request.  Perhaps it is your larger payloads that are swamping your server so it can't respond to incoming new socket requests?

Comment: Thank you jfreind! I analysed more into my code and found out that even when my js + paint+layout is taking < 17milliseconds, my FPS is still < 60, i figured the websocket notifications "onmessage" call is triggered 2 and sometimes 3 times in a particular frame by looking into chrome devtools timeline. Though websockets "onmessage" call doesnt takes > 3 milliseconds but it occurs 2 or more times within a frame that is causing the FPS to drop below 60. I dont know what to share here in the code as i think this question is more related to websockets and animationFrame fundamentals, i am new2 em.